# Mixing two buffers of the same concentration, but of different pH

Tags: acid-base

Does anyone know how to approach this?

I have two buffers of the same weak acid of the same molarity **but at different pH**

Let's say the pH of one was 8 and one was 7, how do I go about getting a pH of 7.6?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You're going to need that pKa.

Comment: What are the values of all pKa of each ones ?